# Utility to lock window position & size of windows in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Either selectively or globally for windows - is there a way to lock window position and size of windows in Windows 7?

I couldn't find anything in Group Policy to disable resizing or moving of windows, so perhaps there is a utility or something in the registry of Windows that disables this?

Comment: I don't think this functionality is baked-in.  Are you open to major shell alternations and/or 3rd party software?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of program that you can click on a window and capture its current position and size, and it will watch for if it changes and then put it back, so quickly that if you try to drag a window it won't let you. For instance, it would monitor the event handlers for moving windows to know when its attempted and either circumvent or immediately undo the change.

Comment: I'd like something like this that *prevents* any change in window size.  I accidentally press *Restore Down* in Adobe Audition, and when I press *Maximize* again, all the panes are in the wrong position and I have to manually reposition every one.  (Of course this is Adobe's fault, but good luck getting them to fix it.)

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/467908/how-to-prevent-windows-from-being-resized

Answer (score 4):

Try a window manager

http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm

> WindowManager helps you to improve your work flow by remembering and restoring the position and size of your programs and windows. Many programs don't remember their position and size between sessions and even Windows explorer does not always restore windows to their last position. This is where WindowManager steps in and makes sure your windows are placed exactly where you want them every time you open them. WindowManager even allows you to lock the position and size of any window, so that it will always open at the same spot no matter where you move it. The window handling is fully customizable and you can set up special rules for your favorite or most frequently used windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the desired window size and position and then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the <kbd>X</kbd> in the top right to close the application, then this size and position become the default next time you open the application. With some non-standard applications you may have to do this twice to set it.

Answer (score 0):

This tool should also help. The binaries can be found under "**releases**":
https://github.com/OgmiosVoice/WindowLock

**How it works**
WindowLock will query the list of windows from the OS and in case of applications with multiple windows it will search for the top-left most one (within a given range) marking it as a main window, and then will reposition all of the other windows to the position of this main window. Since having multiple monitors or large monitors is more and more common WindowLock supports multiple main windows within the same application: thus having one browser on the left side of the screen and another window on the right side of the screen will create two separate groups for repositioning the newly created windows.